# I defined some multiple functions and how would u write one more req that would combine all these calls to have a final ret?

Tags: python

Here is an example when I were to define one more request initiate_call()
..it should combine all the oututs of the following calls and comebine returns from each and output one final ret. what is the best way to structure this.

```
def makeA(): 
  return {"name": "steve"}

def makeB(): 
  return {"street": "new York"}

def makeC():
  return {"city": "NY"}
```

final ret to be like {"name": "steve", "street": "new york", "city": "NY"}

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to immutably merge three dictionaries together? There are multiple dups on that, but the exact answer depends on things like: Does it have to be a `dict`, or would, e.g., a `ChainMap` work? Is there any chance of duplicate keys, and, if so, what do you want to happen? Anyway, there's a canonical question that covers most of the possibilities, so I'll link this as a dup, and if there's some way in which your specific question isn't answered by that, please add a comment, edit your question, and we can reopen it.

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Anyway, for 3.x, the short version is probably either `dict(makeA().items() | makeB().items() | makeC().items())` or `dict(collections.ChainMap(makeC(), makeB(), makeA()))`, but you should read all of the answers.